# INSERT is blocking UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to understand why **uncommitted** inserts for a table are blocking update operations. For this I created a sample database with "READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT = ON" and "ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION = ON".

Test case is like this.

1. Preparation

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [group] [int] NOT NULL,
        [first name] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
        [last name] [nchar](20) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_1] ON [dbo].[Table_1] ([id] ASC)WITH ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    
    INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (1, 1, 'Joe', 'Joee'), (2, 1, 'Foo', 'Bar'), (3, 2, 'Hank', 'Hanko')
    GO
```

2. In session 1 run an insert and do NOT commit

```
    begin TRAN;
    INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (4, 1, 'Hans', 'Hansen')
```

3. In session 2 using "read committed snapshop" isolation level run an update

```
    begin tran;
    UPDATE Table_1 SET [last name]='no name' WHERE [group]=1
```

Result: Session 2 will be lock waiting for a key lock until session 1 is committing the transaction.

[image: key lock]

Rows versioned by Session 1 are not conflicting with Rows versioned by Session 2. After reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189050(v=sql.105) I assume only modified rows should be versioned and blocking other update/exclusive lock requests.

WORKAROUND: using isolation level "Snapshot" for Session 2

**EDIT 1**: I missed to mention that I also tried with a Non-Clustered Index for the "group" column.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [group_index] ON [dbo].[Table_1] ( [group] ASC ) WITH ( ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The situation is unchanged:
[image]

**EDIT 2**: Same scenario on oracle works as I expect it to work. The update does only process the rows that are visible for him since the rows from the insert are not committed yet. Identical Oracle scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1 (p_id int NOT NULL, p_group int NOT NULL, first_name char(20) NOT NULL, last_name char(20) NULL);
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (1, 1, 'Joe', 'Joee');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (2, 1, 'Foo', 'Bar');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (3, 2, 'Hank', 'Hanko');
```

Transaction 1 - do not commit!

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (4, 1, 'Hans', 'Hansen')
```

Transaction 2 (read committed)

```
UPDATE Table_1 SET last_name='No Name' WHERE p_group=1;
```

-> 2 rows updated.

Comment: Indexes are your friend for performance and concurrency. Without an index on `Group` a full scan is required for the update and will be blocked by the insert.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I forgot to mention that I already tried with index on Group and get similar behavior. Post above is edited to reflect this.

Comment: @oj34 don't try to second-guess the server with `WITH ( ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)`. Indexing and locking aren't broken. Snapshot isolation isn't broken either. The index prevents `UPDATE` from locking the entire table. `INSERT` modifies the index as well, so it *needs* a lock on the index.

Comment: In fact, the row you're inserting would be affected by that `UPDATE`, so it makes no sense for `UPDATE` to proceed when one of the rows it needs is already locked. Snapshot isolation doesn't mean that locked rows are invisible, or that you can perform two conflicting changes to the same field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: as a side note: Postgres and Oracle would do exactly that: only UPDATE the rows that are visible to that transaction - at least with `read committted` isolation level - serializable would result in an error. And the UPDATE would only lock the rows it changed, regardless whether they were found by a table scan or an index lookup. Maybe oj34 expects snapshot isolation to work the same as other MVCC implementations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure SQL Server would act differently - I avoid long running transactions as far as possible. MVCC isn't free, in any database. This is a contrived situation and I suspect an XY Problem - why would blocking here be an issue unless there was a transaction running longer than it should? One could use the `READPAST` hint but why is there a long-running transaction?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that exactly my understanding. The update should only process the rows that are committed and since there is NO conflict on the committed rows it should not be blocked. Just tried the very same on Oracle and only committed rows are processed.